# Android image gallery with buttons and detail activity

Tags: android, image-gallery

I would like to make a gallery in android studio which would display thumbnails of images in a folder with, for each image, a button to delete the image. When one clicks the image it triggers another activity (via intent) to display the image in full screen.

I was thinking of using a custom GridView, and for each item (custom class) an ImageView and an ImageButton. Or should I use fragments (I have never used them).

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: sounds like your spot on, create a grid view.  launch a new activity with each click.   Sounds like a perfect start.  Moving to fragments could come later.

Comment: Then my GalleryActivity should have an onItemClickListener() which would start the DetailActivity? Wouldn't that mean that it would be a click on the item (ImageView + ImageButton) or can one differentiate between clicking the ImageView or the ImageButton?

Comment: @MatthewShearer Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Gallery `Activity` would have a `GridView` which in turn needs an adapter.

Inside the `Adapter` you would inflate each view, with a `ImageView` and an `ImageButton`

you would then assign independent click listeners to each view.

something like

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }
    Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               // launch activity
          }
    });

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_imagebutton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               // launch activity
          }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Comment: you should probably also look at using a Recyclerview with a grid layout manager but it's the same principle

Comment: It's working now, separate actions for the button and the imageView which starts the detail activity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem at all.